# UIStackView with multiple label

Tags: uistackview

Is it possible to create UIStackview without fixed height constraint.
I have two label. Height of both label are dynamic. UIStackview should expand if labels expand. How to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For vertical UIStackView, add your UILabels and make their
`vertical content hugging priority` to `1000`
Now your UIStackView height will depend upon you labels height.